# Filtering on parent of a parent in Dynamic Data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have the following relationship in my model

Restaurant -> Cuisine -> Item

On Item's List page, I need to be able to filter directly by restaurant. How would one go about doing that in a ASP.NET Dynamic Data Application ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just simulated your problem using **EntityDataSource** and everithing is work fine. Consider two way to solve your problem.

The first way is to use **QueryExtender** control and **SearchExpression**. More detail information you can found by link [SearchExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.expressions.searchexpression.aspx) with examples.

Real example of this you can find from Steve's blog about Dynamic Data by link [Multi-Column Search](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2011/01/adding-multi-column-search-to-default.html). And if you implement Steve's approach to your Dynamic Data site, all you need to do is to change your **Item** metadata, for example,

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(Item.ItemMetadata))]
[MultiColumnSearch(
    "Item_Name", 
    "Item_Info", 
    "Cuisine.Restaurant.Restaurant_Name")]
public partial class Item
{
    internal sealed class ItemMetadata
    {
        public string Item_Name { get; set; }
        public string Item_Info { get; set; }
        public Cuisine Cuisine { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And now you can search on custom *List.aspx* page for **Item** by Restaurant name (for example). It was the first way.

The second way is to use **Where** property of **EntityDataSource** on **Item** *List.aspx* page.

Simple example:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource 
    ID="ItemGridDataSource" 
    runat="server" 
    EnableDelete="true" 
    OnSelecting="ItemGridDataSource_Selecting"
    OnSelected="ItemGridDataSource_OnSelected"
    Where="it.Cuisine.Restaurant.Restaurant_IsClose=false" />
```

or you can use

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ItemGridDataSource.WhereParameters.Add(new Parameter("it.Cuisine.Restaurant.Restaurant_Name", TypeCode.String, yourValueFromDropDownForExample));
}
```

in Code-behind.

More information: [EntityDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**P.S.**

I would like to recommend you a great book **ASP.NET Dynamic Data Unleashed** by Oleg Sych where you can find more detailed information about extended filtering in Dynamic Data.